# jQueryMobile and ASP.NET GridView pager links

Tags: gridview, jquery-mobile

Have .NET GridView control on page. jQueryMobile brakes URLs for pager. For example
instead of postback : javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$phContent$gvContactList','Page$2')

it tries go to anchor on page
http://localhost:1172/Server Side/mobile/ContactList.aspx#javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$phContent$gvContactList','Page$2')

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think giving the links a `rel="external"` should stop jquery mobile from handling it this way.